# Difference between Activator.CreateInstance() and typeof(T).InvokeMember() with BindingFlags.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, .net

Forgive me if this question has already been asked and answered.

Given a class of type T, what is the difference between the following?

```
T myObj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

T myObj = typeof(T).InvokeMember(null, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null);
```

Is one solution preferred over the other?

Comment: FWIW: `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` is more correct for your first example, as it won't require a cast of the result to `T`.

Comment: @Steve Guidi:  Thanks.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Decompiling `RuntimeType.InvokeMember` yields this fragment:

```
if ((bindingFlags & BindingFlags.CreateInstance) != BindingFlags.Default)
{
    if (((bindingFlags & BindingFlags.CreateInstance) != BindingFlags.Default) && ((bindingFlags & (BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod)) != BindingFlags.Default))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_CreatInstAccess"), "bindingFlags");
    }
    return Activator.CreateInstance(this, bindingFlags, binder, providedArgs, culture);
}
```

In other words, `InvokeMember` with those `BindingFlags` calls `Activator.CreateInstance`. It goes through several more call layers (checking bindings, verifying arguments) before getting down to business. `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` is much more succinct:

```
public static T CreateInstance<T>()
{
    bool bNeedSecurityCheck = true;
    bool canBeCached = false;
    RuntimeMethodHandle emptyHandle = RuntimeMethodHandle.EmptyHandle;
    return (T) RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(typeof(T) as RuntimeType, true, true, ref canBeCached, ref emptyHandle, ref bNeedSecurityCheck);
}
```

**EDITED** You might expect the latter to be faster, but a method called `RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow` also calls `RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance` to do the work; it's used as a fallback if an Activator cache entry for the constructor can't be found. I'd do some performance testing if you're looking for the fastest solution of the two.