# What version of .NET containing RuntimeMethodHandle.EmptyHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

No one answers my question in [Difference between Activator.CreateInstance() and typeof(T).InvokeMember() with BindingFlags.CreateInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295344/difference-between-activator-createinstance-and-typeoft-invokemember-with-b/2500960#2500960).  I guess that the issue is closed and I am asking here again.

Ben M have a nice function which I need for a project.  The function is -

```
public static T CreateInstance<T>() 
{ 
    bool bNeedSecurityCheck = true; 
    bool canBeCached = false; 
    RuntimeMethodHandle emptyHandle = RuntimeMethodHandle.EmptyHandle; 
    return (T) RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(typeof(T) as RuntimeType, true, true, ref canBeCached, ref emptyHandle, ref bNeedSecurityCheck); 
}
```

I am using .NET 3.5 and Visual studio 2008. It gives the error "EmptyHandle type name does not exist in the type System.RuntimeMethodHandle".

Then I used "RuntimeMethodHandle emptyHandle = new RuntimeMethodHandle();". Another error presents. RuntimeTypeHandle does not have a CreateInstance method either. Activator has. But it does not take any ref parameter.

Thanks for clarification in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't have been asking a *question* by adding an *answer* to another question. Writing a new question (as you've done here) is the right approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EmptyHandle` is an internal static property on `RuntimeMethodHandle`. From Reflector:

```
internal static RuntimeMethodHandle EmptyHandle {
    get {
        return new RuntimeMethodHandle(null);
    }
}
```

Luckily, you don't have to implement the method yourself - use [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx) (Ben M's 'nice function' was just the decompiled source code for that .NET class method).

Comment: Property, not method - but otherwise, yes :)

Comment: "Get accessor method"? ;) (D'oh)

Answer (score 1):

I see no indication that it exists [even in .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtimemethodhandle_members(v=VS.100).aspx) - at least publicly.

I suspect it may be an internal property, but if that's the case you should treat it as if it didn't exist.