# Activator.CreateInstance with optional parameters

Tags: reflection, .net-4.0, optional-parameters

Does anyone know how to instantiate a class using a constructor which has just 1 parameter that is optional?

I've tried both

```
(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { Type.Missing });
```

and

```
(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { });
```

To no success... I'm getting MissingMethodException

Comment: Optional arguments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This worked:

```
(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 
                    BindingFlags.CreateInstance |
                    BindingFlags.Public |
                    BindingFlags.Instance | 
                    BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,null, new object[] {Type.Missing },CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: For those who ran across this answer and was tripped up by the [MSDN Comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) "This flag should only be used with Type.InvokeMember", hopefully [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295344/difference-between-activator-createinstance-and-typeoft-invokemember-with) will save you the time it took me to ensure that calling `Activator.CreateInstance` is also a safe usage of that `BindingFlags` enumeration